# Graph such that each path is induced

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to know the name, if there is one, for a graph with the property that every path in it is an induced graph (hence a snake). I'm also interested in any characterization of such a graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a simple, undirected graph $G$. Define $\mathcal{P}$ as the property that every path $P$ in $G$ is an induced subgraph of $G$. Suppose $G$ satisfies property $\mathcal{P}$. Further assume that $G$ contains a cycle $C_k$ on $k$ vertices with $V(C_k)=\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k\}$ as an induced subgraph, then $P_{k}$ with $V(P_{k})=\{v_1,v_2,\cdots, v_{k}\}$ is a path in $G$. But $(v_{k},v_1) \notin E(P_{k})$ by definition of a path, hence $P_{k}$ is not induced. A contradiction. We can conclude that $G$ is cycle-free.

Therefore, the family $\mathcal{T}$ of graphs satisfying $\mathcal{P}$ are cycle-free (forests).